# How to show dates in a jFormattedTextField using postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I want to show dates in a JformattedTextField, using the partern day/month/year, however, I only can show "yyyy-mm-dd" because this is how the postgresql send to java, How can I transform to the partern I want to use?

The JformattedTextField has this format "##/##/####"

Normally, the database show "yyyy-mm-dd" in the textfield without a mask, that means, the database is sending me a data, but i need to use a mask showing me dd/MM/yyyy and if the mask is on, i get nothing on the jFormattedTextField

I already saw the orther topic about it, but, i could not resolve my problem

```
            if(rs.next()){
            
            jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setText(rs.getString("cad_cpf"));
            jTextFieldNOME.setText(rs.getString("cad_nome"));
            jTextFieldIDADE.setText(rs.getString("cad_idade"));
            jTextFieldAPELIDO.setText(rs.getString("cad_apelido"));
            jTextFieldDATA.setText(rs.getString("cad_data"));
           

        jFormattedTextFieldPROCURAR.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
        jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldNOME.setEnabled(true);
        jTextFieldIDADE.setEnabled(true);
        jTextFieldDATA.setEnabled(true);
        jTextFieldAPELIDO.setEnabled(true);
        jButtonExcluir.setEnabled(true);
        jButtonALTERAR.setEnabled(true);
        jButtonSalvar.setEnabled(false);
        jButtonINSERIR.setEnabled(false);
        

        }
```

Comment: The proper solution would be to use a date field in your database, instead of storing it as a string. Then you can retrieve it as a `java.time.LocalDate` (or `java.sql.Date`, though that should only be used for legacy purposes). Then when you display it, you can use an appropriate format.

Comment: Actually, i'm using a date field in my database, also, i'm trying to save and show day of birth.

Comment: Then use `getObject(..., LocalDate.class)` instead of `getString(...)` and use an appropriate formatter to obtain the string value.

Comment: Like that?

`jTextFieldDATA.setText(rs.getObject("cad_data"), LocalDate.class);`

Comment: That won't compile, because a `java.time.LocalDate` is not a String. You would first need to convert it to a string using a [formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with your preferred format.

Comment: I did this:

`Date data = rs.getDate("cad_data");
                
                String Date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                jTextFieldDATA.setText(Date);`

But now, i'm getting the system date, I need to get the date on the postgresql

Comment: That is because you're using `format(new Date())` instead of `format(data)`. But really, I recommend you switch to using the more modern `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `java.sql.Date` (use `rs.getObject("cad_data", LocalDate.class)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to convert to date, so, first you need to receive date on the format the database is saved, them, convert to the format you want, in my case dd/MM/yyyy

Here is the solution I'm using for this problem:

```
                if(rs.next()){

                jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setText(rs.getString("cad_cpf"));
                jTextFieldNOME.setText(rs.getString("cad_nome"));
                jTextFieldIDADE.setText(rs.getString("cad_idade"));
                jTextFieldAPELIDO.setText(rs.getString("cad_apelido"));

                String Date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(rs.getDate("cad_data"));
                jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setText(Date);

                jFormattedTextFieldPROCURAR.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
                jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setEnabled(false);
                jTextFieldNOME.setEnabled(true);
                jTextFieldIDADE.setEnabled(true);
                jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setEnabled(true);
                jTextFieldAPELIDO.setEnabled(true);
                jButtonExcluir.setEnabled(true);
                jButtonALTERAR.setEnabled(true);
                jButtonSalvar.setEnabled(false);
                jButtonINSERIR.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This seems like a valid answer, but in general, it's often useful to include a bit more context about how and why this answers the question.